# Can there be too much training?

Tags: training, brazilian-jiu-jitsu, competition

My oldest son (19) teaches and trains BJJ 6 days a week. He teaches and takes morning, afternoon and evening classes, plus trains MMA, does fitness training and is currently learning some boxing.

My younger two (12 and 13), train 5 days a week (they have the opportunity to train 6, but I make them take a day off midweek).

My 13 year old son assists in teaching some classes and trains a minimum of 2 classes 5 days a week.
My 12 year old daughter trains just the single class 5 days a week.

I encourage my younger two to walk to and from school, as I think walking is a great way to maintain a general fitness and stamina.

I have seen questions about the minimum training a student should do. Given my children's ages and the fact the oldest does it full time for a living; can  too much training affect performance?

My younger two have taken a break from comps for six months, but will resume next year; is there a regime that maximises comp performance?

Comment: You've got two questions in this, really; the first (main) question about the level of training for your oldest son, the second about a competition performance regime for your youunger kids. Ideally, the second question should be a separate question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There can be too much training, but everything you've described here sounds fine. If a student is overtraining they'll notice decreased performance on the mat, sluggishness all day, difficulty sleeping, persistent hunger, and other signs. Frequent training is fine as long as the student builds up training frequency slowly and remains on point with their sleep, nutrition, and workout intensity.

Fitness.SE has [some](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/9698/1771) [Q&A](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/2396/1771) [on](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6803/1771) the topic.

Answer (score 2):

physically they can probably do it. The 19 year old, if he's t the level he can really teach classes can probably train and roll all day, though a rest day would be best.

With the youngest, too much training will be when they no longer want to go anymore but will have to be dragged to school.

Answer (score -2):

Let yourself and your participants rest. Consecutive training isn't healthy. Remember what happened to Bruce Lee. You must rest, eat, relax for a day or two.

Answer (score -3):

The body needs to rest to adapt or it won't develop properly and will breakdown. You can and should have daily workouts, however you should never train* two days in a row. Also, never train force and endurance the same day.

*(as in being exhausted at the end of the day)

Comment: Many successful competitors train daily, even twice a day. I, like many casual amateurs, train multiple days in a row with no ill effect.

Comment: With being exhausted at the end of the day ? I don't think so.

Comment: You'd be wrong. Some people train hard.

Comment: I train twice a day every day, am freaking pooped twice a day. I take sundays and wednesday nights off. Sometimes I take a few days break, but that's more to refresh my brain. Your body will get used to it, and his 19 year old kid's body has probably grown up with it for the past few years (assuming he's been training for a few, if he's instructing). His body is probably expecting and looking forward to the exercise.

Comment: Yes, the body does need rest, but the thing is to train different things on different days... if you wear out your legs one day, work on the core or arms the next.  You can train every day as long as you focus a differently each day.